# Apache Phoenix UDF not working on server side

Tags: apache, hbase, user-defined-functions, apache-phoenix

**1** I have created jar with custom UDF function and copied jar into **dynamic.jar.dir** so when I use my UDF function as part of `SELECT` I getting result without issues.

**2** But when function is a part of `WHERE` clause I getting error that class of my custom function is not found.

```
select PK FROM "my.custom.view" where MY_FUN(ARRAY["COLF"."COL1"], 'SOMEPARAM')  limit 1;
```

---

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: BooleanExpressionFilter failed during reading: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myCompany.phoenix.MyCustomFunction
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:96)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.throwIOException(ServerUtil.java:62)
    at org.apache.phoenix.filter.BooleanExpressionFilter.readFields(BooleanExpressionFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.phoenix.filter.SingleKeyValueComparisonFilter.readFields(SingleKeyValueComparisonFilter.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Writables.getWritable(Writables.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Writables.getWritable(Writables.java:101)
    at org.apache.phoenix.filter.SingleCQKeyValueComparisonFilter.parseFrom(SingleCQKeyValueComparisonFilter.java:50)
    ... 16 more
```

**base-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:57000/user/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>localhost</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>21081</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </property>

    <!-- SEP is basically replication, so enable it -->
    <property>
        <name>hbase.replication</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily</name>
        <value>128</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.fs.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp/hbase</value>
    </property>

<property>
    <name>phoenix.functions.allowUserDefinedFunctions</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.dynamic.jars.dir</name>
    <value>${hbase.rootdir}/lib/</value>
  </property>

<property>
  <name>fs.hdfs.impl</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Manually adding jar with:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal -f /my.jar hdfs:///user/hbase/lib/my.jar
```

For function creation using:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MY_FUN(BINARY[], VARCHAR) RETURNS BOOLEAN as 'com.myCompany.phoenix.MyCustomFunction' using jar 'hdfs://localhost:57000/user/hbase/lib/my.jar';
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar when I upgraded to Phoenix 5.0 from 4.7. I got an exception stating that I now needed to place my UDF .jar into /apps/hbase/data/lib due to permission issues. In the old environment I was able to get away using the /apps/hbase/lib directory. Maybe this is happening to you as well but it's not alerting you to the new path change.